# add a function on Page Load in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pageload, region

I have the folowing javascript code, what it does its loads a Map with different regions, when you hover or click over a country, it will display aditional information about that country in the right side of the map.

What i want to do is when the page loads, a random country is already showing information, without a hover or clic.

live example here: http://roneskinder.com/fm/image-map/index.htm

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/easySlider1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            controlsBefore: '<p id="controls">',
            controlsAfter: '</p>',
            continuous: true
        });
    }); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      jQuery("#map-container AREA").mouseover(function () {
            var regionMap = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-map';
            var regionList = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-list';
            jQuery(regionMap).css('display', 'inline');

            // Check if a click event has occured and only change the Region hover state accodringly
            if (!jQuery('#practice-container ul').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery(regionList).css('display', 'inline');
            }
        }).mouseout(function () {
            var regionMap = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-map';
            var regionList = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-list';

            // Check if a click event has occured and only change the Region hover state accodringly
            if (!jQuery(regionMap).hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery(regionMap).css('display', 'none');
            }

            // Check if a click event has occured and only change the Region hover state accodringly
            if (!jQuery('#practice-container ul').hasClass('selected')) {
                jQuery(regionList).css('display', 'none');
            }
        });

        jQuery("#map-container AREA").click(function () {
            jQuery('#map-container img.region').removeClass('selected').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#practice-container ul').removeClass('selected').css('display', 'none');

            var regionMap = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-map';
            var regionList = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-list';
            jQuery(regionMap).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');
            jQuery(regionList).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');
        });

    });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    <form runat="server">
    <div id="map-view-container">
    <div id="map-container">
        <img src='transparentMap.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' alt='' usemap='#regionMapView'
            class='map' />
        <map name='regionMapView' id='regionMapView'>
            <area shape="poly" coords="101,148,103,139,102,135,112,124,125,118,131,110,135,112,142,107,167,104,181,101,188,102,194,97,193,92,207,99,237,98,250,93,285,107,253,123,238,121,231,129,227,136,210,149,194,147,183,154,174,155,175,171,162,176,158,171,149,170,147,153,136,152,133,158,122,150,113,152"
                href="#Honduras" id="Honduras" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="74,167,62,166,29,167,20,165,9,155,12,148,9,138,24,114,65,107,67,102,57,101,52,95,32,84,41,79,42,69,96,60,102,105,111,105,124,108,125,105,133,106,130,110,126,115,126,118,112,123,102,136,101,148,92,153,83,159"
                id="guatemala" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="157,178,172,191,207,215,214,216,224,213,241,212,257,210,264,215,271,220,280,217,281,212,273,203,278,188,273,192,275,183,276,169,282,180,283,162,283,145,290,129,286,114,288,107,273,110,251,124,237,121,236,127,227,133,226,137,209,149,198,147,184,153,174,155,176,172,157,179,157,178"
                href="#nic" id="nic" />
            <area shape="poly" coords="75,167,82,159,92,156,100,147,113,153,123,151,133,158,138,152,147,154,148,170,151,172,147,174,135,176,124,170,124,174"
                href="#elSalvador" id="elSalvador" />
            <area alt="panama England" shape="poly" coords="311,245,306,257,313,261,309,269,314,277,314,273,329,269,334,273,346,273,353,284,362,286,365,283,363,280,368,279,370,285,370,292,382,294,388,285,397,285,397,279,399,276,387,266,399,263,408,254,407,248,420,243,432,248,441,253,447,259,458,255,446,268,463,283,469,276,479,256,473,247,475,244,466,240,443,230,423,230,414,226,377,245,368,250,339,246,336,248,335,254,330,246,320,244,312,244"
                href="#panama" id="panama" />
            <!--                <area shape="poly" alt="southEast" id='southEast' coords="96,60,102,55,106,56,114,44,120,41,123,44,130,41,130,57,127,66,131,76,121,98,111,104,102,105"
                href="#southEast" />-->
            <area id="crica" alt="crica" shape="poly" coords="212,222,216,216,232,213,257,210,273,220,285,216,290,223,297,231,308,240,317,244,310,245,308,251,306,257,313,261,308,268,313,278,305,278,294,267,288,267,297,273,297,277,281,274,278,266,281,261,253,244,244,237,234,234,233,236,245,244,242,249,228,244,218,243,213,235,219,228,213,221"
                href="#crica" />
            <area id='london' shape='poly' alt='London' coords='186,365, 186,360, 187,360, 187,359, 188,359, 188,358, 189,358, 189,357, 191,357, 191,356, 192,356, 192,355, 196,355, 196,356, 198,356, 198,357, 200,358, 200,359, 201,359, 201,360, 203,360, 203,362, 202,362, 202,364, 200,364, 199,365, 198,366, 195,366, 194,367, 193,367, 193,368, 191,368,190,367, 188,367, 188,366, 187,366, 187,365'
                href='#london' />
        </map>
        <img src='mvCostaRica.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region crica-map'
            alt='Costa Rica' />
        <img src='mvPanama.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region panama-map'
            alt='Panama' />
        <img src='mvGuatemala.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region guatemala-map'
            alt='Guatemala' />
        <img src='mvHonduras.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region Honduras-map'
            alt='Honduras' />
        <img src='mvElSalvador.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region elSalvador-map'
            alt='El Salvador' />
        <img src='mvNicaragua.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region nic-map'
            alt='Nicaragua' />
        <!--            <img src='mvBelice.png' width='481' height='350' border='0' class='region southEast-map'
            alt='Belice' />-->
        <img src="mvCentralAmerica.png" width="481" height="350" class="regionBg" />
    </div>
    <div id="practice-container">
        <!--Nicaragua-->
        <ul class="nic-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe1" src="../image-slider/nicaragua/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--El Salvador-->
        <ul class="elSalvador-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe2" src="../image-slider/elSalvador/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Honduras-->
        <ul class="Honduras-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe3" src="../image-slider/honduras/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Belice-->
        <ul class="southEast-list">
            <li>
                <img src="images/0.png" alt="" /></li>
        </ul>
        <!--Panama-->
        <ul class="panama-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe4" src="../image-slider/panama/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Guatemala-->
        <ul class="guatemala-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe5" src="../image-slider/guatemala/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Costa Rica  -->
        <ul class="crica-list">
            <li>
                <iframe id="iframe6" src="../image-slider/costaRica/index.html" height="350" width="430"
                    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: i tried to create the javascript function myself, but did not succeed, i did manage to make the random array but have no idea on how to assign it in the map. The array gives back the id of the items but dont have a clue on how to make it work from there.

    keywords = ["crica","panama","guatemala","Honduras","elSalvador","nic"]
    var keyword = keywords[Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length)]

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it fine, I can't really think without the visual stuff

```
keywords = ["crica","panama","guatemala","Honduras","elSalvador","nic"]
```

Then random function

```
var keyword = keywords[Math.floor(Math.random()*keywords.length)]
```

So you got a lot of stuff right here

```
    jQuery("#map-container AREA").click(function () {
        jQuery('#map-container img.region').removeClass('selected').css('display', 'none');
        jQuery('#practice-container ul').removeClass('selected').css('display', 'none');

        var regionMap = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-map';
        var regionList = '.' + $(this).attr('id') + '-list';
        jQuery(regionMap).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');
        jQuery(regionList).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');
    });
```

You'll need to change the click function for a new document ready and replace the AREA thing with the keyword. If a hash works better for you then:

```
document.location.hash = keyword;
```

You're doing it fine, you can do it.

Comment: tried this with no luck at all... can anyone help me resolve this pls, im losing my mind 
`$(document).ready(function () {
keywords = ["crica", "panama", "guatemala", "Honduras", "elSalvador", "nic"]
var keyword = keywords[Math.floor(Math.random() * keywords.length)]
            
jQuery("#map-container " + keyword);
var regionMap = '.' + $(this).attr(keyword) + '-map';
var regionList = '.' + $(this).attr(keyword) + '-list';
jQuery(regionMap).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');
jQuery(regionList).addClass('selected').css('display', 'inline');`